# Eclipse: copy *only* the error message

Tags: eclipse

Can I copy only the error message from Eclipse Problems with instead of this entire message:

Severity and Description    Path    Resource    Location    Creation Time   Id
1120: Access of undefined property sort.    clientApp/src   Filters.mxml    line 36 1270460218964   798

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is:

- to display the property of the error message (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>),
- and copy the "Description" field.

[alt text http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/3327/eclipseerrorview.png](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/3327/eclipseerrorview.png)

Comment: are you sure you can select it ? I opened that window and I tried to select the text, but I couldn't (is maybe because I'm using Eclipse-based Flex builder ?)...

Comment: @Patrick: I confirm: not only you can select it, but actually the error message in the description field is selected *by default*. All you need to do is a CTRL+C, and you are done.

Comment: I starred your answer because I guess it is correct. However on my Flex Builder on MAC I cannot make it work. If I press APPLE+C from the error window, I copy (as described in the question) a lot of additional text. If I open the window you suggested, I cannot select the text to copy paste it.

Comment: @Patrick: Mac... I didn't know. I have not much experience on Eclipse development on a Mac, so I cannot be sure it can work that way with this kind of configuration.